# how to select day for week Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a column for a day of the week where values will be Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...

and then apply a filter only for Friday.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
df = (
      spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.fact_table')
     .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start,end))
     .filter(f.col('is_client_plus')==1)
     .filter(f.col('source')=='tickets')
     .filter(f.col('subtype')=='trx')
     .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1) 
     .withColumn('week', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'YYYY-ww'))
     .withColumn('month', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'M'))
     .withColumn('HP_client', f.col('customer_id').isNotNull())
     .withColumn('local_time',f.from_utc_timestamp(f.col('trx_begin_date_time'),'Europe/Brussels'))
     .withColumn('Hour', f.hour(f.col('local_time')))
     .withColumn('Day', f.day(f.col('local_time')))
     .filter(f.col('Hour').between(4, 8))
     )
```

Here is the error I get:

> AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'day'

How can I create a column for on a dayli basis? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `F.dayofweek`, which returns an integer (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ..., 7 = Saturday).

Alternatively, you can use `F.date_format('local_time', 'E')`, which returns a string like `'Sun', 'Mon'`, etc.

`'EEEE'` returns the string in full, e.g. `Sunday`, etc.